# Overriding remote DNS with some local DNS for all users of a domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with a DNS, but the problem is our website is available form a different IP form outside (say 83.3.3.3) and different from inside (say 192.168.0.3). So is it possible to add a rule that (localy) would resolve www.mydomain.com to a 192.168.0.3 (while still resolving to 83.3.3.3 for the outside world)? Note that I would like to set it for all users of the internal network - something like etc/hosts but for all internal users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ISC Bind, which supports views. It return different addresses to different hosts.

http://zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html

Comment: We'll have to try that out, but seems to be exactly what we want :-).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm undesrstanding what you're asking, you'll need to create a zone on the internal DNS server for mydomain.com and then add an A record for www that resolves to the internal ip address of the web server.

Comment: You should mention that if he creates a zone on the internal DNS he will have to clone every RR from the public DNS below `mydomain.com` to the local server. Otherwise any Resource Record of `mydomain.com` that is only registered on the public DNS won't be accessible from the clients using the internal DNS.

Comment: What if we already have an alias named www that refers to external IP?